# Is there a set-of-sets where sets can be addressed by any of their members?

Tags: java, set

I'm trying to find a data-structure in Java (or Groovy) that where something like this works:

```java
MemberAdressableSetsSet mass = new MemberAdressableSetsSet();
mass.addSet(["a","b"]);
mass.addSet(["c","d","e"]);
mass.get("d").add("f");
String output = Arrays.toString(mass.get("e").toArray());
System.out.println(output); // [ "c", "d", "e", "f" ] (ordering irrelevant)
```

Does anything like that exist? And if not, is there a way to implement something like this with normal Java code that doesn't give the CPU or the memory nightmares for weeks?

Edit: more rigorously

```java
MemberAdressableSetsSet mass = new MemberAdressableSetsSet();
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>();
s1.add("a");
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();
s2.add("c");s2.add("d");s2.add("e");
mass.addSet(s1);
mass.addSet(s2);
Set<String> s3 = new HashSet<String>();
s3.add("a");s3.add("z");

mass.addSet(s3);
/* s3 contains "a", which is already in a subset of mass, so:
 * Either
 *   - does nothing and returns false or throws Exception
 *   - deletes "a" from its previous subset before adding s3
 *      => possibly returns the old subset
 *      => deletes the old subset if that leaves it empty
 *      => maybe requires an optional parameter to be set
 *   - removes "a" from the new subset before adding it
 *      => possibly returns the new subset that was actually added
 *      => does not add the new subset if purging it of overlap leaves it empty
 *      => maybe requires an optional parameter to be set
 *   - merges all sets that would end up overlapping
 *   - adds it with no overlap checks, but get("a") returns an array of all sets containing it
 */

mass.get("d").add("f");
String output = Arrays.toString(mass.get("e").toArray());
System.out.println(output); // [ "c", "d", "e", "f" ] (ordering irrelevant)
```

`mass.get("d")` would return the `Set<T>` in `mass` that contains `"d"`. Analogous to how get() works in, say, `HashMap`:

```java
HashMap<String,LinkedList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(9);
map.put("d",list);
map.get("d").add(4);
map.get("d"); // returns a LinkedList with contents [9,4]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does `get("d")` mean exactly?  What should happen if with `get("d")` if `"d"` is in more than of the sets?  Do you expect to be able to do something like this:  `set s = ["a","b"]; mass.addSet(set); s.add(...);` and have that also update the mass set?   What exactly is the type of `["a", "b"]`?  It isn't valid Java syntax.

Comment: Also,  what type does `get(..)` return?  (And does it need to?)  State your minimal acceptable requirements in terms of complexity for various operations `addSet`, `get`, `add` and any other operations that you require.  (In other words tell us what "CPU or the memory nightmares" means in more rigorous language.)

Comment: @StephenC Better?

Comment: You didn't answer the questions about complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with so far looks like this:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class MemberAdressableSetsSet {
    private int next_id = 1;
    private HashMap<Object,Integer> members = new HashMap();
    private HashMap<Integer,Set> sets = new HashMap();
    public boolean addSet(Set s) {
        if (s.size()==0) return false;
        for (Object member : s) {
            if (members.get(member)!=null) return false;
        }
        sets.put(next_id,s);
        for (Object member : s) {
            members.put(member,next_id);
        }
        next_id++;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean deleteSet(Object member) {
        Integer id = members.get(member);
        if (id==null) return false;
        Set set = sets.get(id);
        for (Object m : set) {
            members.remove(m);
        }
        sets.remove(id);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean addToSet(Object member, Object addition) {
        Integer id = members.get(member);
        if (id==null) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if (members.get(addition)!=null) return false;
        sets.get(id).add(addition);
        members.put(addition,id);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean removeFromSet(Object member) {
        Integer id = members.get(member);
        if (id==null) return false;
        Set s = sets.get(id);
        if (s.size()==1) sets.remove(id);
        else s.remove(member);
        members.remove(member);
        return true;
    }
    public Set getSetClone(Object member) {
        Integer id = members.get(member);
        if (id==null) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        Set copy = new java.util.HashSet(sets.get(id));
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Which has some drawbacks:

- Sets are not directly accessible, which makes all `Set` methods and properties not exposed by explicitly defined translation methods inaccessible, unless the clones are an acceptable option
- Type information is lost.

  - Say a `Set<Date>` is added.
    It would not complain about trying to add, for example, a `File` object to that set.

At least the lost type information for the Sets doesn't extend to their members: the `Set.contains()` still works exactly as expected, despite both sides having been typecast to `Object` before being compared by `contains()`. So a set containing `(Object)3` won't return true when asked whether it contains `(Object)3L` and vice versa, for example.

> A set containing `(Object)(new java.util.Date(10L))` *will* return true when asked whether it contains `(Object)(new java.sql.Date(10L))` (and the other way round), but that's true even without the `(Object)` in front, so I guess that's "works as intended" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

How often do you need to access by one element? Might be worth using a map and storing the same `Set` reference under multiple keys.

I would prevent external mutation to the map and sub sets, and provide helper method to do all of the updates:

```
public class MemberAdressableSets<T> {
    Map<T, Set<T>> data = new HashMap<>();

    public void addSet(Set<T> dataSet) {
        if (dataSet.stream().anyMatch(data::containsKey)) {
            throw Exception("Key already in member addressable data");
        }
        Set<T> protectedSet = new HashSet<>(dataSet);
        dataSet.forEach(d -> data.put(d, protectedSet));
    }

    public void updateSet(T key, T... newData) {
        Set<T> dataSet = data.get(key);
        Arrays.stream(newData).forEach(dataSet::add);
        Arrays.stream(newData).forEach(d -> data.put(d, dataSet));
    }

    public Set<T> get(T key) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(data.get(key));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could update the `addSet` and `updateSet` to create new `Set` instances if the key doesn't exist and make `updateSet` never `throw`. You'll also need to extend this class to handle the cases of merging sets. i.e. handle the use-case:

```
mass.addSet(["a","b"]);
mass.addSet(["a","c"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows for things like `mass.get("d").add("f");` to affect the subset stored in `mass`, but with major drawbacks.

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MemberAdressableSetsSetDirect {
    private LinkedHashSet<Set> sets;
    public void addSet(Set newSet) {
        sets.add(newSet);
    }
    public Set removeSet(Object member) {
        Iterator<Set> it = sets.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Set s = it.next();
            if (s.contains(member)) {
                it.remove();
                return s;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public int removeSets(Object member) {
        int removed = 0;
        Iterator<Set> it = sets.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Set s = it.next();
            if (s.contains(member)) {
                it.remove();
                removed++;
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }
    public void deleteEmptySets() {
        sets.removeIf(Set::isEmpty);
    }
    public Set get(Object member) {
        for (Set s : sets) {
            if (s.contains(member)) return s;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Set[] getAll(Object member) {
        LinkedHashSet<Set> results = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Set s : sets) {
            if (s.contains(member)) results.add(s);
        }
        return (Set[]) results.toArray();
    }
}
```

There's no built-in protection against overlap and thus we have unreliable access, as well as introducing the possibility of countless empty sets that need to be periodically purged with a manual call to `deleteEmptySets()`, as this solution can't detect if a subset was modified by direct access.

```java
MemberAdressableSetsSetDirect massd = new MemberAdressableSetsSetDirect();
Set s1 = new HashSet();Set s2 = new HashSet();Set s3 = new HashSet();
s1.add("a");s1.add("b");
s2.add("c");s2.add("d");
s3.add("e");
massd.addSet(s1);massd.addSet(s2);
massd.get("c").add("a");
// massd.get("a") will now either return the Set ["a","b"] or the Set ["a","c","d"]
// (could be that my usage of a LinkedHashSet as the basis of massd
//  at least makes it consistently return the set added first)
massd.get("e").remove("e");
// the third set is now empty, can't be accessed anymore,
// and massd has no clue about that until it's told to look for empty sets
massd.get("c").remove("d");
massd.get("c").remove("c");
// if LinkedHashSet makes this solution act as I suspected above,
// this makes the third subset inaccessible except via massd.getAll("a")[1]
```

Additionaly, this solution also can't preserve type information.
This will not even give warnings:

```java
MemberAdressableSetsSetDirect massd = new MemberAdressableSetsSetDirect();
Set<Long> s = new HashSet<Long>();
s.add(3L);
massd.addSet(s);
massd.get(3L).add("someString");
// massd.get(3L) will now return a Set with contents [3L, "someString"]
```